# Shmot 24:3, why is there no preposition?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, mishpatim

In [Shmot 24:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.24.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the second half of the pasuk reads, "וַיַּ֨עַן כָּל־הָעָ֜ם ק֤וֹל אֶחָד֙ וַיֹּ֣אמְר֔וּ כָּל־הַדְּבָרִ֛ים אֲשֶׁר־דִּבֶּ֥ר יְק֤וָ֖ק֤ נַֽעֲשֶֽׂה" "and all the people answered in unison and said, "All the words that the Lord has spoken we will do."

However, though the English is [explained](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9885) as "IN unison" (or in [other](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.24.3?lang=bi&with=Onkelos%20Exodus&lang2=en) places, "with one voice"), the Hebrew has no introductory preposition, reading only "kol echad" -- one voice.

Is there any reason why the text would not include a preposition which would introduce the word kol so it could be "in" or "with" (as it is in places like Bereishit 39:14)? Could it mean that the people responded "one voice"? The same "kol echad" is used in D"H 2, 5:12 but the Chabad site has it as the object of the verb "l'hashmi'a" meaning "to make one sound".

Looking for explanation as to possible other meanings which account for the lack of the prepostion.

Comment: Ezra 10:12, Shemot 19:19 seem relevant